# JPA OneToMany not deleting child even with orphanRemoval = true

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

When i try to delete Meal from MealCategory nothing happens,i even added "orphanRemoval = true", i am not getting any error.I am using Spring boot with JPA/Hibernate and SQL

public class MealCategory

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "meal_category_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Integer id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mealCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Meal> meals;
package Models.Database;
```

public class Meal

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "meal_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Integer id;
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "meal_category_id")
private MealCategory mealCategory;

@OneToOne( orphanRemoval = true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonIgnore
public Item item;
```

public class Item

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "item_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Integer id;


@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="meal_id")
private Meal meal;
private String description;
private Integer numberOfMeals;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_table_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Order order;
```

public class Order

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "order_table_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Integer id;

private boolean isStarted;
private boolean isDone;
private boolean isTaken;
@Column(unique=true)
private LocalDateTime date;
private Integer tableNumber;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Item> items;
```

Comment: It would be good to have the minimal reproducible example of the issue. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: where is the code you used to delete `Meal` and what is the relation of the `Order` and `Item` classes with your problem ?